# Behaviour of Maximal tenor product with inductive limits

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I am trying to prove the following result:

> Let $(A_{i})_{i\in I}$ be an inductive system of non unital $C^{\ast}$-algebras with connecting homomorphisms $f_{ij}: A_{i} \to A_{j}$ and let's denote the limit by $A$. If $B$ is another non unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra, we would like to show that the inductive limit of $(A_{i}\otimes_{\rm{max}} B)_{i\in I}$ is isomorphic to $A\otimes_{\rm{max}} B$

I know the proof of this in case of unital $C^{\ast}$-algebras but i cant see the proof for non unital case. Any ideas?

Comment: what a coincidence, I am a tenor, too!

Comment: @AlvinLepik : Cheers!